# Resultant Vector Algorithm for 2D Collisions

Tags: collision-detection, physics, collision-resolution

I am making a Pong based game where a puck hits a paddle and bounces off. Both the puck and the paddles are Circles. I came up with an algorithm to calculate the resultant vector of the puck once it meets a paddle. The game seems to function correctly but I'm not entirely sure my algorithm is correct. Here are my variables for the algorithm:

**Given:**
velocity = the magnitude of the initial velocity of the puck before the collision
x = the x coordinate of the puck
y = the y coordinate of the puck
moveX = the horizontal speed of the puck
moveY = the vertical speed of the puck

otherX = the x coordinate of the paddle
otherY = the y coordinate of the paddle
piece.horizontalMomentum = the horizontal speed of the paddle before it hits the puck
piece.verticalMomentum = the vertical speed of the paddle before it hits the puck

slope = the direction, in radians, of the puck's velocity
distX = the horizontal distance between the center of the puck and the center of the paddle
distY = the vertical distance between the center of the puck and the center of the paddle

**Algorithm solves for:**
impactAngle = the angle, in radians, of the angle of impact.
newSpeedX = the speed of the resultant vector in the X direction
newSpeedY = the speed of the resultant vector in the Y direction

---

Here is the code for my algorithm:

```
int otherX = piece.x;
int otherY = piece.y;
double velocity = Math.sqrt((moveX * moveX) + (moveY * moveY));

double slope = Math.atan(moveX / moveY);
int distX = x - otherX;
int distY = y - otherY;

double impactAngle = Math.atan(distX / distY);

double newAngle = impactAngle + slope;
int newSpeedX = (int)(velocity * Math.sin(newAngle)) + piece.horizontalMomentum;
int newSpeedY = (int)(velocity * Math.cos(newAngle)) + piece.verticalMomentum;
```

for those who are not program savvy here is it simplified:

```
velocity = √(moveX² + moveY²)
slope = arctan(moveX / moveY)
distX = x - otherX
distY = y - otherY

impactAngle = arctan(distX / distY)

newAngle = impactAngle + slope
newSpeedX = velocity * sin(newAngle) + piece.horizontalMomentum
newSpeedY = velocity * cos(newAngle) + piece.verticalMomentum
```

**My Question:**
Is this algorithm correct? Is there an easier/simpler way to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: In game development, 'it seems to function correctly' is all you need.

Comment: I haven't attempted to dissect your code, but...a elastic circle--circle collision is easy looked at in the right way. It's the same old angle of impact equals angle of rebound you get with a circle--plane collision, only you measure relative their common tangent at the point of impact. If you want to include inelastic behavior or spin effect things get rather harder.

Comment: @dmckee not too much for inelastic, spin behavior makes it evil though(iirc angular impulse and friction come into play)

Comment: Possibly related: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3430/new-vector-calculation-for-elastic-collision-of-circle-and-fixed-rectangle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, for games, all you need is "it seems to function correctly".

I'm not sure if your code is correct (looks a bit off, but I haven't looked at it too closely).

Here's a more efficient formula that avoids trig and square roots:

[math formula http://mathbin.net/equations/91525_0.png](http://mathbin.net/equations/91525_0.png)

Simplifying into components, where:

[distX equation http://mathbin.net/equations/91527_0.png](http://mathbin.net/equations/91527_0.png), same for y:

http://mathbin.net/equations/91527_1.png

http://mathbin.net/equations/91527_2.png

In code:

```
 int otherX = piece.x;
 int otherY = piece.y;
 int distX = x - otherX;
 int distY = y - otherY;    
 double dotprod=(distX*moveX+distY*moveY)/(distX*distX+distY*distY)
 newSpeedX=2distX*dotprod+moveX
 newSpeedY=2distY*dotprod+moveY
```

### For `newAngle`

AFAICT, you only need this variable for calculating the velocities, but if you need it for something else as well, you may use this:

`newAngle`  can be calculated by:

[newAngle calculation http://mathbin.net/equations/91528_0.png](http://mathbin.net/equations/91528_0.png)

Simplified,

[simplified newAngle calculation http://mathbin.net/equations/91529_0.png](http://mathbin.net/equations/91529_0.png)

In code:

```
newAngle=arccos(dotprod*Math.sqrt((distX*distX+distY*distY)/(moveX*moveX+moveY*moveY)))
```

Or, you could use your old method to calculate newAngle, this one involves an inverse trig function and a square root, while yours involves two inverse trig functions--pretty much the same load on the computer IMO (both functions are solved via power series usually).

Comment: +1 Thank you for the answer, I'm going to use your algorithms to simplify my code, if nothing better comes up when its migrated ill give you the answer

Comment: @John. No problem.. DavidZaslavsky is going to be inactive for this week, so I asked dmckee to do the migration... Just out of interest, do you need `newAngle` anywhere else in the code after this collision bit? If so, why?

Comment: @Manishhearth i might use it later depending if i want the player to be able to `spin` the ball, but I'm not sure if I'm going to add that or not. I left it in the question just in case.

Comment: In that case its better to just use a collision simulating API. The people at gamedev may know a few. (I think Box2D may work, but I'm no expert)

Comment: This seems like its not getting migrated, therefore you helped me the most so ill give you the credit for the answer

Comment: @John: Uhh, this answer will be migrated as well. So if you accept it here, it will be shown as accepted on gamedev.SE, and half the crowd won't bother to look at this question. Rep will also be transferred (with a stagger). So unaccept it right now (you can always unaccept a question), and accept it on gamedev if you don't get any better answers after a few days :)